# Use non-namespaced library in php

Tags: php, oop, spl

I'm writing an application where all classes are using namespaces, and using spl_autoload_register() to load all classes dynamically.

Now I want to make use of a non-namespaced library (WideImage). As WideImage does not use namespaces, spl_autoload_register() does not work. So included the script manually:

```
    require( 'Library/WideImage/WideImage.php');
    $w = new WideImage();
```

But it still tries to autoload; and gives a fatal class not found error.

How can I override this autoload function?

By request:

```
spl_autoload_register(function( $class ) {

  $path       = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . CMS_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  $classFile  = str_replace( '\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class );
  $classPI    = pathinfo( $classFile );
  $classPath  = $path . $classPI[ 'dirname' ] ;

  $file = $classPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $classPI[ 'filename' ] . '.class.php';

  if (file_exists($file)) {
require_once( $file );
  }

});
```

Edit: solution:

Change

```
if (file_exists($file)
to 
if (file_exists($file) && !class_exists($class)) {
```

Comment: move it outside of your autoload directory or give it a namespace ?

Comment: Paste the code for your autoloader function.

Comment: @Dave: changing the path does not make difference. Adding namespace to WideImage would mean going through all classes, changing filenames etc. Don't want to do that for every update :)

Comment: A `IF Statement` in the `autoloader` should be able to solve it.. There you can check if your `$class = "WideImage"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [class_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) before loading.

Comment: Thanks. I changed if (file_exists($file) to if (file_exists($file) && !class_exists($class)). Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

You can register multiple autoloaders with `spl_autoload_register`. This way you can write autoloaders for your own calsses and libraries. They trigger after each other and should return `true` or `false` - if the loaded souccessfully or not.